# Adding three dots (axis break) to Bar Plots in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to plot bars in groups of three. In some of my cases, the values of the bars are such that meaningful differences are obscured by the scale of the axis, which is set by the minimum and maximum values of all bars.  For example, if one bar is around 0.9 and in all other cases all bars are below 0.1, differences among the lower-valued bars will not be apparent on the plot.  It would be useful to be able to specify a break in an axis, to allow different sub-regions of the plot to be scaled appropriately.

Is it possible to create a break or jump in the axis, and ideally in any bars that span the break, to better illustrate this type of data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [BreakPlot](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/21864) FileExchange submission.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution would be to use logarithmic scale on y axis.

But if you want  this I would do:

1. create two plot axes.  With subplot or manual.
2. Plot in both your plot.
3. Then at the lower set Ylim to [0,0.2]
4. At the upper Ylim to [0.9, 1.0]. And turn off X-axe.

Of course values maybe need to be adjusted. 
Basically it takes you there.

Afterwards you can do some cosmetics - like turning the figure background to white, or add some dots between the curves...